# Viewpager + Listview + setOnItemClickListener and fragment replace

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, onitemclicklistener

I browsed StackOverflow for days before deciding to post my own question. I really can't figure this out.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to implement a viewpager with 2 tabs. I managed to get a ListView on the first tab and everything is working perfectly, at least until I click on one of the list items.

Here's the interesting code in my SherlockListFragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
      // Click event for single list row

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          HashMap<String, String> videoz = new HashMap<String, String>();
           videoz = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
           String videoid = "test";

           Prova singleitem = new Prova();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("KEY_ID", videoid);

              singleitem.setArguments(bundle);                 
               FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

               trans.replace(R.id.main_layout, singleitem);
               trans.addToBackStack(null);
               trans.commit();

        }

  });

}
```

This code actually works and open up my "Prova" fragment, but it breaks everything. It appears below my admob (which is normally sticked to the bottom) and the tab bar doesn't work anymore. What am I missing here?

Listview with tab bar still working: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceasu.jpg
After clicking an item:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYDzx.jpg

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/main_layout"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<com.google.ads.AdView 
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"   

     />
</LinearLayout>      
</LinearLayout>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!